# How to build dependency on neighboring events into predictive models?

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, supervised-learning

I need to classify a list of events: each events is either A or NOT A

As it turns out, if the nth event is A, then the (n+1)th event is more likely to be A.

How would I go about adding this probabilistic component into a supervised learning model?

Thanks!

Comment: I heard today that a Hidden Markov Model might do the trick. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis of this short description, I'd go with a (first-order) Markov model, i.e. factorize the joint probability as

$$
P(a_1, a_2 ... ) = P(a_1) P(a_2 \vert a_1 ) P(a_3 \vert a_2) \ldots
$$
($a_i$ is the variable for the "A-value" of the i'th observation) where the same $2\times2$ probability table is used for each of the factors.  Estimating the probability table is a straightforward process of counting up how often each combination $(a,a), (a, \lnot a), (\lnot a , a), (\lnot a, \lnot a)$
come up as sequential pairs in the data (I'm assuming that you have a large amount of data).